# Unity Google Play Games Plugin Won't Compile in Xcode iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Whenever I try to compile my Unity game in Xcode I get a 3 compile errors which are coming from the Unity Google Play Games plugin:

```
GPGSAchOrLbDelegate.h - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'GooglePlayGames/GooglePlayGames.h' file not found

GPGSRealTimeRoomDelegate.h - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'GooglePlayGames/GooglePlayGames.h' file not found

GPGSManager.h - Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 'GooglePlus/GooglePlayGames.h' file not found
```

I've no idea why this is happening, I followed all the setup instructions correctly.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved this myself by removing the plugin and starting afresh, and then starting a completely new xcode project rather than appending to an old one.

Irritating and time consuming but I got there in the end!

Answer (score 1):

one gotchya is they recently changed many of the method names in the library, in a recent update...

it's possible this has caught you out?

It's very hard to resolve this, but I found some discussion about this for example here,

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/679424/google-play-games-plugin-for-unity-not-authenticat.html

it's a bit easier on iOS than Android.

---

Alternately: note that, essentially, you have not included the GooglePlayGames.h file. Include the link to "which" instructions you were following, to guess which step is problematic. (Most Unity plugins - like Prime31  - have a "preprocessor" stage that does that for you or in the case of Android fills in the damned manifest.  Something is going wrong at that stage.)

Comment: I awarded you with the bounty Joe because your answer was helpful for those people searching who cannot afford to start a whole new project in xcode, so thanks for that! I have added a link to the instructions I was following for posterity.